# CGAL mesh optimization

Tags: triangulation, cgal, delaunay

I have been trying to "clean" a triangulation that I pre-generate.

Essentially I want to input my points on CGAL and generate a mesh from there, then use refine_mesh_3 to remove slivers and improve its quality.

Is there any easy technique to do so?

Thankk...

Comment: There's [optimesh](https://github.com/nschloe/optimesh) (a tool of mine), but cannot handle tet meshes yet.